# How to assert dynamic output

Tags: regex, dynamic, output, behat

I am developing a library for interaction with a local payments' provider server.

Basically, I first want it to generate a `<form>` with hidden `<input>`s, without the wrapping `<form>` tag.

For that I have a feature file where I have specified the following:

```
# GeneratePaymentFormData.feature
Feature: GeneratePaymentFormData
  In order to display a payment button with the corresponding `<form>` and `<input>`s to the user
  As a developer
  I need to be able to supply specific input parameters to my library and have it returning a whole bunch of hidden `<input>` tags with specific values.

  Scenario: Send POST request to estcard.ee
    Given Parameter "private_key_file" is "private.key"
    And Parameter "merchant_id" is "11223344"
    And Parameter "feedback_url" is "http://localhost/myapp/callback.php"
    And Parameter "amount" is "0.19"
    And Parameter "currency" is "EUR"

    When I click on Pay
    Then the output should be
      """
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="gaf"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="ver" value="004"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="11223344"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="ecuno" value="201601149511"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="eamount" value="000000000019"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="cur" value="EUR"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="datetime" value="20160107121111"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="charEncoding" value="UTF-8"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="feedBackUrl" value="http://localhost/myapp/callback.php"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="delivery" value="S"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="mac" value="a9502a893e014072788551a4d7420e9a67ed63782cc9aa7b4b0d4f7b402472dd725fe585f6ba537f3994e259c7b9070a24e1af06a1f87aab0d4f90826925599f6f74d5fb2ce8f79f881ef8face1af6d1913b7e020065a10e6195070f191b71fed49619547bf07e6fc762481e0b307eab0b4775fdb4c1af0cadf260eb6ba0df5c"><br>

      """
```

The problem is that the library has to output dynamic data. For example, the ecuno field is generated from current date and time, followed by a random number. And the field *mac* is a concatenated string of all the values (including the ones having random values), hashed with sha1 and then signed with `openssl_sign()` and then converted to hexadecimal.

How do I test that my library's output is as expected when some parts of it changes every time even when the input parameters are all the same? I suppose I have to use regex while verifying the output but how exactly?

Comment: And what exactly would you be trying to test? You could just ignore values that use randoms?

Comment: That _is_ the question. I'm guessing I should either ignore dynamic parts of the output or somehow mock PHP's time() and random() functions, so that the output would always be the same in the test or implement the whole function first in Behat test and then copy paste it to the actual code. It would first seem ridiculous but then again, when I will refactor or change the function, I can be sure that it still spits out the expected output...

Comment: How people usually test a method that does complex calculations which involve having randomness?

Comment: To do random testing you'd need a second model to test against. One that discreetly calculated an expected value for the input. If you're coding as an individual that's probably not that helpful to you. For individual coding, I'd recommend you create a test set with expected inputs and outputs. And use that test set's inputs rather than randoms to verify your code.